# How access ListElement roles dynamically in JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, qt, qml

I want to write a Function in javascript that sorts a qml ListModel by given role, using Quicksort. My Problem: I dont know how I can pass the needed role dynamically to the function.

A minimal Example:

```
ListModel {
    id: exampleList
    ListElement { value1: "one"; value2: "two" }
}
```

And the javascript Function:

```
function printValue(model, index, role) {
console.log(model.get(index).value1) //works
console.log(model.get(index).role) //doesnt work, but I need something like this
}
```

I tried to call the function with `printValue(exampleList, 0, value1)`, and `printValue(exampleList, 0, "value1")`. Both ended up with "undefined". How can I access the roles dynamically? In my program I have a lot more roles, and the user should be able to sort by all.

Comment: try `model.get(index)[role]` when role should be string

Comment: Thank you, that works fine =)